# Make top border equal to width of the text in nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the width of the top border equal to that of the text in my nav bar.

Is it possible? Here is a screenshot of what I actually want:

[image]

```css
/*menu styling starts here */

#top-menu {
  width: 700px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#top-menu ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  max height: 23.5px;
}

#top-menu ul li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 63px;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#top-menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #a0ce4e;
  border-top: solid #a0ce4e;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a container whithout padding right and without padding-left.

```css
p
{
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
text
</p>
```

Comment: ^ this. With the notice that he may want to have vertical paddings, so using padding-left & padding-right instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use (leaft and right) `margin` instead of  `padding` to create the horizontal distance between the list items.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to remove the horizontal padding from the anchor element as that will always be displayed within the border. Then you can either add a margin to the anchor or padding to the containing list element.

```css
   /*menu styling starts here */

#top-menu  { width : 100%;
            display : block;
            float : right;
            margin : 0px; padding :0px;
            background-color : pink;
           }

#top-menu ul li { display : block;
               float : left;
               max height : 23.5px;
               padding:20px; -- Add padding to list element
             }

#top-menu ul li a { font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size : 16px;
                font-weight : 300;
                line-height : 63px;
                color : black;
                padding : 8px 0px; -- Horizontal padding removed from anchor
                text-decoration :none;
                --margin:20px; -- Alternative: add margin to anchor
              }
#top-menu ul li a:hover { color : #a0ce4e;
border-top : solid #a0ce4e;}
```

```html
<div id="top-menu">
<ul>
<li><a>Title 1</a></li>
<li><a>Title 1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```